# Consecutive daily user visits

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 website in which I'm trying to get the number of consecutive days users have visited my website. StackOverflow has this and it's reported on open your profile. Doing this in `AccountController` and its `Login` action is pretty easy:

```
if (dbUser.LatestLogin == null || ((DateTime)dbUser.LatestLogin).Date != DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
{
    if (dbUser.LatestLogin != null && (DateTime.UtcNow.Date - ((DateTime)dbUser.LatestLogin).Date).TotalDays == 1)
        dbUser.Consecutive++;
    else
        dbUser.Consecutive = 1;
}
dbUser.LatestLogin = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

However, I want to track the users which have checked the `Remember Me` checkbox to stay logged in. How can I do this?

Note:
One thing that came to my mind is to create a global attribute and do this for every action (`if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)`) but I don't think that's a good idea because I have to load the user info for every single request and run the check. Efficiency is very important here.

Comment: You can create an action that does this and call it in the `_Layout.cshtml`. The disadvantage is that this will hit the data base  on every page request. You could set a flag in the `Session` object to mark that you already incremented the value. You need to pair it with `Request.IsAuthenticated`, of course.